# How should I implement List annotation, which contains any type of objects?

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

I want to create List annotation, which supposed to be universal, so I have:

```
from typing import List, Any
lst: List[Any]
lst = [1, 2, None, "string", 1.1]
```

Is it the right way of implementation, isn't it?

Comment: You can tell it is not by running:
```from typing import List, Any;
lst: List[Any];
lst = 1;
print(lst)```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? You can just check that, yes, this implementation is correct as far as a typechecker is concerned.